# trigger in sql problem

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, triggers

this is my trigger

```
ALTER trigger [dbo].[addpay]
on [dbo].[pays]
after insert
as
declare @idtutor int
set @idtutor =(select idtutor from inserted)
begin 
insert into pays (idtutor,nopay,datex,paythismonth)values (@idtutor,600,GETDATE(),'no')
end
```

but it doesn't add a new pays after inserted a tutor... i dont watch any bug, mistake, why doesn't it work

my tables

```
create table Tutor
(
[IdTutor] int primary key identity not null,
[Nombre] varchar(150) not null,
[ApellidoPaterno] varchar (150) not null,
[ApellidoMaterno] varchar (150) not null, 
[EstadoCivil] varchar (10) not null,
[FechaNacimiento] varchar(50),
[Municipio] varchar(150) not null,
[Estado] varchar(150) not null,
[Direccion] varchar(250) not null,
[Sexo] varchar (9) not null,
[TelefonoTutor] char(10) not null,
[CelularTutor] char(15) not null,
[EmailTutor] char(50) not null,
[Empresa] varchar(150) not null,
[Ocupacion] varchar(250) not null,
[DireccionEmpresa] varchar (250) not null,
[TelefonoEmpresa] char(10) not null,
[CelularEmpresa] char(15) not null,
[EmailEmpresa] varchar(50) not null
)



create table pays
(
idpay int primary key not null identity,
idtutor int not null,
nopay float,
datex datetime,
paythismonth varchar(2)
)
```

Comment: Well it won't work correctly at all for multi row inserts. Are you saying that it also doesn't work for single row inserts? Also are you sure you have created it on the correct table? Which table are you doing the insert of a tutor on? It seems odd that the trigger for insert on `pays` would insert another new row to `pays`. Is that definitely the desired effect?

Comment: @Martin i created it in pays table, isn't it ok, there? i want when i add a tutor automatically it adds a row in a pays table

Comment: You would need to create it on the table that you are inserting the tutor to. Is that a different table? If so what is the structure of that table?

Comment: @Martin yes it is another table i will add tables in code ..

Comment: BTW I'm not sure if you get notification of answer edits. I forgot to add `SET NOCOUNT ON` to my original answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create the trigger on the table for where you want it to fire when a new record is inserted (`Tutor` in this case).

Additionally you need to remember that inserts/update statements can affect multiple rows so assigning to scalar variables won't work. The trigger you need is

```
CREATE TRIGGER YourTrigger
ON [dbo].[Tutor]
AFTER INSERT
AS
  BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON

      INSERT INTO pays
                  (idtutor,
                   nopay,
                   datex,
                   paythismonth)
      SELECT idtutor,
             600,
             GETDATE(),
             'no'
      FROM   inserted
  END
```

You will also need to drop the other trigger in your question with `DROP TRIGGER [dbo].[addpay]`